# QsortFilterProxyModel Removing multiple columns

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

In my FilterProxyModel I would like to Remove columns 2 and 5 from my view. So I am doing like this

```
proxy_filter->removeColumns(2,1);
proxy_filter->removeColumns(5,1);
```

However only column 2 is removed and column 5 is still present any suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Better reimplement filterAcceptsColumn(), that's the API for filtering

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used QsortFilterProxyModel before but I think the issue happened because the column index has changed

```
proxy_filter->removeColumns(2,1); // column 2 is removed.
proxy_filter->removeColumns(5,1); // then column 5 now is column 4
```

Let remove column 4 instead!